# How to display wordpress category name by shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, shortcode

```
    function Service_shortcode($atts , $content = null){
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title'=>'',
        ),$atts
        ));
        $q = new WP_Query(
            array('posts_per_page'=>3, 'post_type'=>'services')
            );

            $list = '
                <h1>'.$title.'</h1>
                <ul>
            ';
            while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();          
                $list.='
                    <li>
                        <h3>'.get_the_title ().'</h3>
                        <h6>'.the_category(',').'</h6>
                        <p>'.get_the_content().'</p>
                    </li>
                ';
            endwhile;
            $list.='</ul>';
            wp_reset_query();

        return $list;
            }  
        add_shortcode('service','Service_shortcode');
```

when use it the_category(',') in theme it's show the category name but when use it in shortcode not working. which code use to show category name by shortcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
function categories_list_func( $atts ){
     $categories = get_the_category();

         if($categories) {
            foreach($categories as $category) {
                $output .= '<li class="cat-' . $category->cat_ID . '"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "Read more posts from : %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></li>';
            }
            $second_output = trim($output);
          }
          $return_string = '<h4>'.__( "Categories :", "my_site").'</h4><div class="overflow"><ul class="post-categories">' . $second_output . '</ul></div>';

     return $return_string;

    } // END Categories
    add_shortcode( 'categories-list', 'categories_list_func' );
```